# JavaScript redirect in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been struggling with this for a while but I can't seem to figure this out.
I've got a modal that displays and asks for user login and password. Right now if user ==admin it should redirect to Google but for some reason it doesn't work.

Any indications on why is this happening?

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">
    <div class="center">
        <input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" tabindex="3">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {

        });

        $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({
            top: 110,
            overlay: 0.45,
            closeButton: ".hidemodal"
        });
    });

    $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if (username == "admin") {
            window.location.href = "http://kegan.ing.puc.cl/~grupo6/faseiv/index.php";
        } else {
            alert("Usuario o contraseña invalido");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code is weird, and I don't exactly know how to edit it to make it better.  You have a `</div>` before your `<script>` tag that seems out of place, and seem to have extra `})` after `leanModal`.  Can you make sure the code you posted is the code you're using?

Comment: ^ With proper indentation you'd see that

Comment: Can you verify that username is admin with a `console.log` in your click function?  If so, you're properly setting a redirected page to http://kegan.ing.puc.cl/~grupo6/faseiv/index.php , but that's not google.

Comment: That's the code I'm actually using.
@RUJordan what do you mean by proper indentation? It's very difficult to me to find misaligned <divs> or something like that in Sublime. What else can I do?

Comment: It was mangled when I last saw it, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looking at it first, your `$('#loginbtn')` code is **outside** your DOM ready scope. Secondly, I'd remove that selector completely and bind your code to the **form's submit event** - it's much more accurate than the submit buttons click.

```
$(function() {
    $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if (username == "admin") {
            window.location.href = "http://kegan.ing.puc.cl/~grupo6/faseiv/index.php";
        } else {
            alert("Usuario o contraseña invalido");
        }
    });
});
```

...if you were to continue to use the **click** handler on your submit button, you need to stop `#loginform` from submitting normally.

Comment: It now works flawlessly, thanks. However, I don't get whats the DOM ready scope.

Comment: `$(function() {` is your DOM ready scope, it's the same as `$(document).ready)function() {` and basically says don't execute anything in this function until the DOM is ready (around when page is finished loading)